# how can I sort the rows in two different tables according to the generated date

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql

In my web project, user can ask questions and publish articles. I keep the questions in the question table and the articles in the articles table. How can I sort the data of these two tables according to the date of creation between them?
I am using Linq-to-SQL.

Comment: What have you tried? How is the behavior of your code different than what you expect? See the [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with Lews. More info would be good. What isn't working for you? Have you tried a simple Linq2Sql join? Something like:

```
var select =
from a in _db.Articles
join q in _db.Questions
on a.CreateDate equals q.CreateDate
select a;
```